# App crash report in device logs

Tags: iphone

I'm facing a problem with a crash after testing my application for more than 20 minutes. It is crashing somewhere but I'm not able to find where it is crashing. I enabled NSZombiaEnable but still, I don't get any correct report.

Below is my device crash log:

```
Nov 22 23:49:31 unknown UserEventAgent[12] <Notice>: jetsam: kernel termination snapshot being created
Nov 22 23:49:31 unknown com.apple.launchd[1] <Notice>: (UIKitApplication:com.apple.mobilemail[0x56d0]) Exited: Killed: 9
Nov 22 23:49:31 unknown com.apple.launchd[1] <Notice>: (UIKitApplication:com.yqlabsEnterprise.ticketPadPUSHCHAT[0xee8a]) Bug: launchd_core_logic.c:3733 (25562):0
Nov 22 23:49:31 unknown com.apple.debugserver-64[1522] <Warning>: 1 [05f2/1303]: error: ::read ( 4, 0x2ff179d4, 1024 ) => -1 err = Bad file descriptor (0x00000009)
Nov 22 23:49:31 unknown com.apple.launchd[1] <Notice>: (UIKitApplication:com.yqlabsEnterprise.ticketPadPUSHCHAT[0xee8a]) Bug: launchd_core_logic.c:3732 (25562):3
Nov 22 23:49:31 unknown com.apple.launchd[1] <Notice>: (UIKitApplication:com.yqlabsEnterprise.ticketPadPUSHCHAT[0xee8a]) Assuming job exited: <rdar://problem/5020256>: 10: No child processes
Nov 22 23:49:31 unknown com.apple.launchd[1] <Warning>: (UIKitApplication:com.yqlabsEnterprise.ticketPadPUSHCHAT[0xee8a]) Job appears to have crashed: Segmentation fault: 11
Nov 22 23:49:31 unknown SpringBoard[51] <Warning>: Application 'Mail' exited abnormally with signal 9: Killed: 9
Nov 22 23:49:32 unknown SpringBoard[51] <Warning>: Application 'ticketPad' exited abnormally with signal 11: Segmentation fault: 11
Nov 22 23:49:32 unknown kernel[0] <Debug>: launchd[1576] Builtin profile: MobileMail (sandbox)
Nov 22 23:49:33 unknown ReportCrash[1575] <Notice>: Saved crashreport to /Library/Logs/CrashReporter/LowMemory-2012-11-22-234933.plist using uid: 0 gid: 0, synthetic_euid: 0 egid: 0
```

Please help me.

Comment: It's possibly a memory problem.  Try turning off zombies and running with Instruments to look at leaks and allocations.

Comment: it is a segfault, not a bad access

Answer (score 0, accepted):

because it isnt a bad access, there wont be a zombie... its segfaulting.

cause #1:
bad format in an NSLog or stringWithFormat :D (at least for me)

cause #2:
if that's not it try looking for c-code you use that may not exist.

(non-existing symbols)

**top hint: cause #3:

the IOS filesystem is case sensitive, maybe the xib name you specify is somehow wrong and it cant load the xib? / a xib itself is corrupt**

cause #4:
google for "Assuming job exited: : 10: No child processes" :D

Comment: Thanks for the Reply , Can you explain me how to resolve this segfaulting cause.

Comment: well if it isnt cause #1 you are maybe calling a c-function thats not there

Comment: But app not get crashed in other iPad's in iPad 1 with ios 5.1.1, 32gb    in that it crashes.